# Lazy load images for UITableViewCells from NSDocumentDirectory?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, ios4, uiimage

I have a `UITableView` in my app in which I load several images from the `NSDocumentDirectory`. It *works*, but when scrolling up and down, the app seems to freeze a bit, most likely because of the images being served in the main thread, effectively blocking the tableView from scrolling until it's loaded. My problem is that I don't know how to load them in later, a "lazy load" feature, while scrolling.

This is the code snippet used to load the images now:

```
imagesPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/images/", [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0]];
if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:[imagesPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%d.png", rowID]]]) {
    UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[imagesPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%d.png", rowID]]];
    // If image contains anything, set cellImage to image. If image is empty, use default, noimage.png.
    if (image != nil){
        // If image != nil, set cellImage to that image
        cell.cellImage.image = image;
    }
    [image release];
}
```

What is the best way to "lazy load" the images in each cell to avoid lagging in the scrolling?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at the [SDWebImage](http://github.com/rs/SDWebImage#readme) repository. It provides everything to perform asynchronous image loading.

**Update**

I just noticed that there is some typos in the README, so downloading a local file may not work as expected.

Here is some sample code. The view controller has an UIImageView outlet and wants to load the `image.jpg` file. It implements the `SDWebImageManagerDelegate` protocol:

```
- (IBAction)loadImage:(id)sender {
    SDWebImageManager *manager = [SDWebImageManager sharedManager];

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *destPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"image.jpg"];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:destPath];
    UIImage *cachedImage = [manager imageWithURL:url];
    if (cachedImage)
    {
        imageView.image = cachedImage;
    }
    else
    {
        // Start an async download
        [manager downloadWithURL:url delegate:self];
    }    
}

- (void)webImageManager:(SDWebImageManager *)imageManager didFinishWithImage:(UIImage *)image
{
    imageView.image = image;
}
```

Comment: I'm not trying to download an image, I'm trying to load in an image from NSDocumentDirectory.

Comment: Downloading should be understood as accessing any resource supported by NSURL. NSURL can be used for several protocols: http, ftp or file. Convert you path to a NSURL and "download" your local file.

Comment: I'm trying to, but it doesn't work! The NSURL is loaded from a string: `file://var/mobile/Applications/RANDOMIDENTIFIER/Documents/images/10.png`.

Comment: Thanks, that will probably work, but I have decided to use the SDWebImage-framework, so that I don't need to take care of downloading and storing images :)

Thanks, though!

Comment: @Laurent Etiemble: I am passing my image path which is from app's Documents Directory. Now when I try and run the app the placeholder images come but the real images do not get loaded even after much time