# Need lazy table image load for images in app's Documents folder

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview, ios4, lazy-loading

I have my images into my iPhone application's documents directory.

I load them into table. But I want them to load as lazy table images.

I have searched the web, but found the links where images are loaded from server. How can I load them from my documents directory?

I tried this link but it didn't work for me:

[Lazy load images for UITableViewCells from NSDocumentDirectory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3012656/lazy-load-images-for-uitableviewcells-from-nsdocumentdirectory)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A working solution that downloads images from a server can easily be modified to load from the NSDocumentsDirectory. Here's a simple implementation that you can create as a stand-alone class or integrate into an existing class. I did not include 100% of the code, just put in enough to show loading the images. `imageLoader.h` needs to define a protocol including `imageLoader:didLoadImage:forKey:` and the iVars/properties for `_delegate` and `_images`.

```
// imageLoader.m

// assumes that that images are cached in memory in an NSDictionary
- (UIImage *)imageForKey:(NSString *)key
{
    // check if we already have the image in memory
     UImage *image = [_images objectForKey:key];

    // if we don't have an image:
    // 1) start a background task to load an image from available sources
    // 2) return a default image to display while loading
    if (!image) {
        // this is the simplest example of background execution
        // if you need more control use NSOperationQueue or Grand Central Dispatch
        [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(loadImageForKey) withObject:key];
        image = [self defaultImage];
    }

    return image;
}

// attempts to load an image from available sources and notifies the delegate when done
- (void)loadImageForKey:(NSString *)key
{
    NSAutoReleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoReleasePool alloc] init];

    // attempt to load the image from a file
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[self imagePathForKey]];

    // if no image, attempt to load the image from an URL here if desired

    // if no image, return default or notFound image
    if (!image) {
        image = [self notFoundImage];
    }

    if ([_delegate respondsTo:@selector(imageLoader:didLoadImage:ForKey:)]) {
        // this message will be sent on the same thread as loadImageForKey
        // you can either modify this to send the message on the main thread
        // or ensure the delegate does any desired UI changes on the main thread
        [_delegate imageLoader:self didLoadImage:image forKey:key];
    }

    [pool release];
}

// returns a path to the image in NSDocumentDirectory
- (NSString)imagePathForKey:(NSString *)key
{
    NSString *path;
    // your implementation here
    return path;
}
```

Comment: If you don't understand anything I wrote than this is a bit beyond being a noob. You need to be familiar with Objective-c concepts and design patterns. You'll also need to learn about the iOS framework and various objects. If you are simply looking for a canned implementation of a class that does remote loading of images into a table from files stored in your apps documents directory, you may be able to find something out there. The code I posted will work but requires integration into a new or existing class implementation. I'm trying to help but I can't write your app for you. Good luck!

Comment: @Julia, not at all. Sorry if my comment came across as harsh. My main point is there is a lot to learn and I would make sure you understand the fundamentals before diving in too deep on specifics you don't understand. When you ask questions in a communal forum like stackoverflow there are a wide range of experience levels represented. It's not too hard to tell where someone is at based on their communications. My comment was meant with all respect. I think it's great that you are diving in and want to learn. We were all noobs once.